# How to determine which button is clicked in dynamically created DataTable

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm creating dynamically data Table bound to Grid View. Every row is populated with button. When i determine which button is clicked on the row, i want to get the current value of cell in clicked button in that row and modify her.Help!

Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
    OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" 
                    CommandName="odzemi" 
                    CssClass="button2" 
                    Font-Bold="True"
                    Text="-" 
                    Width="100px" 
                    OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

//in this way a create row

```
         private void AddNewRecordRowToGrid()
             {         
             int counter;

            if (Request.Cookies["kasa"] == null)

            counter = 0;


        else
        {
            counter = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value);

        }
        counter++;

        Response.Cookies["kasa"].Value = counter.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["kasa"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2);

        if (ViewState["Markici"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {


                    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Democookie"];
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                    drCurrentRow["FirmaID"] = Request.Cookies["firma"].Value; 
                    drCurrentRow["Godina"] = Request.Cookies["godina"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["KasaID"] = Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["MarkicaID"] = Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value; 
                    drCurrentRow["Datum"] = DateTime.Now;
                    drCurrentRow["Masa"] = Session["masa39"];
                    drCurrentRow["VrabotenID"] = Session["New"];
                    drCurrentRow["Artikal"] = Label3.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Cena1"] = Label4.Text;
                  //this is where i need to make changes
                     drCurrentRow["Kolicina"] = Label5.text;
                    drCurrentRow["Smena"] = Session["smena1"];
                    drCurrentRow["VkIznos"] = Label6.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["VkDanok"] = Label8.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["SySDatum"] = DateTime.Now;
                    drCurrentRow["Vid"] = Label23.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Edmera"] = Label10.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["ArtikalID"] = Label33.Text;
                }


                //Removing initial blank row  
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();
                    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();

                }

                //Added New Record to the DataTable  
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.InsertAt(drCurrentRow,0);
                //storing DataTable to ViewState  
                ViewState["Markici"] = dtCurrentTable;

                //binding Gridview with New Row  
                GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                GridView2.DataBind();


            }
        }
    }
```

//in this button i call that method

```
          protected void Button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {     
          AddNewRecordRowToGrid();

           }
```

//
          and here i'm determine clicked button of row, and here in this 
                   dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex]["Kolicina"]= "" i need to 
 get cureent value of cell which is different in every row.

```
         protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];
        var clickedRow = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        var clickedIndex = clickedRow.RowIndex;

       //so here i want to get current value of cell, and modify her            

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex]["Kolicina"] = " ";               

        GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView2.DataBind();


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clickedRow = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    var clickedIndex = clickedRow.RowIndex;
}
```

Provided your GridView *does not have sorting or paging enabled*, from this `clickedIndex`, we can get the corresponding Row of the DataTable like this.

```
dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex]["Kolicina"] = "StackOverflow";
```

Comment: ok, one question more..value in column dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = count; -> that count is counter of clicked button and is different in every row.So i have many counters for many buttons, How to know  here which counter count-- to set up?  dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex]["Kolicina"] = " ";

Comment: it should be `clickedIndex + 1` if what I undertand is true.

Comment: dtCurrentTable.Rows[clickedIndex]["Kolicina"] = "here i want to get  the current value of cell and modify her ";

Comment: show me how you have placed the cell there. update your question and add that itemtemplate

Answer (score 0):

In the RowDataBound event, the EventArgument e should have the index of the current item bound in it.  The code `e.Row.RowIndex` will return the index of the row in the Grid, not necessarily the datasource when you have paging applied.  There is a 'DataItemIndex' property, another index that may give you what you are looking for, depending on what you are trying to do.

The grid also exposes the Rows collection, which you can use a foreach to loop through each one, and access that way too.

Note, the Rows on postback will only be based on the markup posted back through viewstate; the grid knows nothing about your data source (unless you rebind on every postback).